# Show wp_query with field date greater today

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this `wp_query`:

```
$today = date('Ymd');
    $args = array (
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                    'key'   => '$key',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value'   => $today,
                    'type'    => 'DATETIME'
                )
              ),
          );
```

I have a custom field called `date` and I'm trying to make a `wp_query` that show me the posts from a future date (greater than today), in based on the custom field `date`.

By the way, I don't understand in the array the property `key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `key` should point to the name of your custom field:

```
'key'   => 'date'
```

Per the documentation:

> The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the
>   date is stored at the format YYYY-MM-DD and tested with this format

So do notice that unless you're saving the date in exactly that format. Otherwise, you may want to convert both your dates to a Unix timestamp using `strtotime()` and then use a `'NUMERIC'` comparison.